# $g(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if}\; 0\leq t\leq 4 \\ 0 & \text{if}\; t > 4 \end{cases} $ $e^ty'+e^ty=g(t), y(0)=0$ Find $y(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Edit:**
I checked my first solution $y(t)=e^t+e^{-t}$ and it is not correct , I cant understand why.

**ordinary differential equation:**

$g(t) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if}\; 0\leq t\leq 4 \\
0 & \text{if}\; t > 4 \end{cases}
$

$e^ty'+e^ty=g(t), y(0)=0$

Find $y(t)$ (that continues $\forall t\geq 0$)

**My solution:**

**The first case : $0\leq t\leq 4$**

$y'=\frac{g(t)}{e^t}-y \overset{g(t)=1}{\implies} y'=\frac{1}{e^t}-y\overset{divide}{\implies} \frac{y'}{\frac{1}{e^t}-y}=1.$

$\int (\frac{y'}{\frac{1}{e^t}-y})dy=\int 1 dt \implies -ln(\frac{1}{e^t}-y)=t+C \overset{y(0)=0}{\implies} C=0.$

Then $y(t)=e^t+e^{-t}$

**The second case : $t > 4$**

$y'=\frac{g(t)}{e^t}-y \overset{g(t)=0}{\implies}\frac{y'}{-y}=1$

$\int (\frac{y'}{-y})dy=\int 1 dt \implies -ln(y)=t+C $

I get stuck !

How can I find C ? is my solution correct?

I'd be grateful for your help!

Comment: Use the solution you got in $[0,4]$ to get $y(4)$ and use it is initial condition for $t>4$.

Comment: I cant understand why my first solution isn't correct? (I checked this)

Comment: Your solution on $[0,4]$ does not satisfy the initial condition $y(0)=0$.

Comment: Rewrite the DE as $e^ty'+e^ty=(e^ty)'=g(t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interval $(0,4)$, the equation is $y'+y = e^{-t}$, with $y(0)=0$. This can be easily solved to get $y(t)=t e^{-t}$, for $t\in[0,4]$. Now, for $t>4$, we solve $y'+y = 0$, with $y(4)=4 e^{-4}$, which yields $y(t)= 4 e^{-t}$. Finally,
$$y(t)=
\begin{cases}
t e^{-t}, & 0 \leq t \leq 4\\
4 e^{-t}, & t > 4
\end{cases}
$$

This solution is, by construction, continuous, but it  is not $C^1$ as it is not differentiable at $t=4$.

---

Your solution is wrong because you are trying to use a formula for separable equations without actually separating the variables... Solve it as a linear equation, or  start by solving $y'+y=0$ as a separable equation and then use the variation of constants method.

Comment: Another method is using the fact that it is a first-order, linear, inhomogeneous of the type $y'(t)+P(t)y=Q(t)$ with $P(t)=1$ and $Q(t)=e^{-t}$ for $t\in[0,4]$. Once you identify this, you can just plug in the usual formula and solve for $y(t)$.